# Use password parameter in Jenkins as Secret in Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, credentials

I have a Jenkins pipeline job that needs to provide the username and password to checkout from RTC as parameters.

The checkout action can use a userId and password variable, but the Password must be of the class "Secret".

When trying to create a secret using `hudson.util.Secret secret = hudson.util.Secret.fromString("${Build_Password}")`, I get the following error:

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod hudson.util.Secret fromString java.lang.String
```

Is there a way to create a Secret or Credential from parameters?

Answer (score 1):

I had to disable the groovy sandbox. After that, I was able to use the Secret class:

```
hudson.util.Secret secret = hudson.util.Secret.fromString(Build_Password)
```

Answer (score 0):

checkout([$class: 'TeamFoundationServerScm', localPath: 'D:\Build-Code-Scm', projectPath: '$/RootDirectory/SubFolder', serverUrl: 'http://TEST.TEST.com:8080/TEST/TEST', useOverwrite: true, useUpdate: true, userName: 'UNMAME', password: hudson.util.Secret.fromString('PASSWORD'), workspaceName: 'Hudson-${JOB_NAME}-${NODE_NAME}'])

Comment: could you elaborate a bit more on the answer?